# JMeter-what is difference between use ${} or vars.get() to get value of variable

Tags: jmeter

Today when I was debugging my JMeter script, I found a problem that confused me a lot.

1. CSV Data Config element: in CSV, I set variable `userId` to `1001200`

[image]

2. Then run script below, and get different value of "userId" when using `${userId}` and `vars.get("userId")`. I think they should be same value, but it seems not. After run `vars.put("userId", "-111")`, `${userId}` and `vars.get("userId")` get different values:

[image]

so it seems `${}` and `vars.get()` have some difference even though their variable is same, does anyone know the reason?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer provided by @user7294900 refers to the case when *Cache compiled script* option is checked. But even if it's not checked, your script will resolve variables defined as `${varName}` **before** execution, while `vars.get("varName")` is resolved **during** execution.

Before JMeter is about to run any element (sampler, pre- or post-processor), it will take (every) text field and will resolve any variables, functions or inline code, identified by `${...}` to their values available at the time of the evaluation. Thus syntax `${...}` converts variable into a constant string and your code (for Groovy or any other execution engine) will look like this:

```
    log.info("***" + "1001200" + "***");
    log.info("***" + vars.get("userId") + "***");
    vars.put("userId", "-111");
    log.info("***" + "1001200" + "***");
    log.info("***" + vars.get("userId") + "***");
```

Thus no matter how you change variable during execution, it won't change since it's no longer a variable. But `vars.get("userId")` on the other hand, is a function call and will check variable value every single time.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you need to follow [best practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) when scripting and avoid using `${value}`

> When using JSR 223 elements, it is advised to check *Cache compiled script if available* property to ensure the script compilation is cached if underlying language supports it. **In this case, ensure the script does not use any variable using `${varName}` as caching would take only first value of `${varName}`. Instead use : 
>   `vars.get("varName")`**