# Can I use variables across all the threads in the thread groups in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, rate-limiting, test-plan

I'm trying to create a test plan for rate-limiting behavior.
I set a rule that blocks after X requests per minute, and I want to check that I get response code 200 until I reached the X requests, and from then, to get 429. I created a counter that shared between all the threads, but it seems to be a mess because it's not a thread-safe.

This is my beanshell "once only controller":

```
String props_pre_fix = ${section_id} + "-" + ${START.HMS};
props.remove("props_pre_fix" + ${section_id}, props_pre_fix);
props.put("props_pre_fix" + ${section_id}, props_pre_fix);

props.put(props_pre_fix + "_last_response_code", "200");
props.put(props_pre_fix + "_my_counter", "0");
```

and this is the beanshell assertion:

```
String props_pre_fix = props.get("props_pre_fix" + ${section_id});
//log.info("props_pre_fix " + props_pre_fix);

//extract my counter from props
int my_counter = Integer.parseInt(props.get(props_pre_fix + "_my_counter"));

//extract last response code
String last_response_code = props.get(props_pre_fix + "_last_response_code");
log.info("last_response_code " + last_response_code);

//if last seconds is greater than current seconds it means we are in a new minute - set counter to zero
if(last_response_code.equals("429") && ResponseCode.equals("200")){
    log.info("we moved to a new minute - my_counter should be zero");
    my_counter = 0;
}

//increase counter
my_counter++;
log.info("set counter with value: " + my_counter);
//save counter
props.put(props_pre_fix + "_my_counter", my_counter + "");
log.info("counter has set with value: " + my_counter);

if (ResponseCode.equals("200")) {
    props.put(props_pre_fix + "_last_response_code", "200");
    if(my_counter <= ${current_limit}){
        Failure = false;
    } 
    else {
        Failure = true;
        FailureMessage = "leakage of " + (my_counter - ${current_limit}) + " requests";
    }
} 
else if (ResponseCode.equals("429")) {
    props.put(props_pre_fix + "_last_response_code", "429");
     if(my_counter > ${current_limit}){
            Failure = false;
    } 
}
```

I'm using props to share the counter, but I obviously feel that this is not the right way to do it.
Can you suggest me how to do that?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51384973/jmeter-what-is-difference-between-use-or-vars-get-to-get-value-of-variable/51385152#51385152

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible to automatically test this requirement using JMeter Assertions because you don't have access to the current throughput so I would rather recommend considering cross-checking [Response Codes per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseCodesPerSecond/) and [Transactions per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/#Transactions-per-Second) charts (can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/))

All the `200` and `429` responses can be marked as successful using Response Assertion configured like:

[image]

If for some reason you still want to do this programmatically you might want to take a look at [Summariser](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.3/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/reporters/Summariser.java) class source which is used for displaying current throughput in the STDOUT.

Also be informed that [starting from JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting.