# unable to initialise variable which is loaded in JSR223

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to pass the value to a variable which is mentioned under post data parameters tab but the value is not getting initialised.

Below screenshot i have highlighted the variable where the value is initialised,

[image]

In below screenshot i have highlighted the variable where it is assigned

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Double check that your `apidatas` property has expected value using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script). The same applies to all the JMeter Variables generated by your Groovy script.
2. Check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries, if your Groovy script fails somewhere somehow there should be a relevant record in the log.
3. Don't inline [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into Groovy scripts, either use "Parameters" section of go for code-based equivalents instead

Answer (score 0):

Use `props` to get JMeter proprty

```
 String temp = props.get("apidatas");
```

See also [best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51384973/jmeter-what-is-difference-between-use-or-vars-get-to-get-value-of-variable/51385152?r=SearchResults#51385152) in JSR223 scripting

Comment: Still it is not working..even if i initialise by adding string in vars.put it is not getting initialised.did i added the variable in right format under "Http Requests" ?

Comment: @SadhaNanda maybe use Name comment instead of data[comment] also make sure `apidatas` exists with valid value