# JMeter loop index always return 0 in Loop Controller

Tags: jmeter

When I use the command `${__jm__myLoopControllerName__idx}` in JSR223 Sampler, it always returns 0 as the index.

The sampler is in the Loop Controller. But I can see that the CSV file I'm looping is done for each line because in the listener "View Result Tree" I can see in the Request Headers, that the data is from each line. What am I doing wrong ?
Thanks for your help.
M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `vars` to get variable in JSR223 script:

```
String index = vars.get("__jm__myLoopControllerName__idx");
```

variable inside `${}` syntax is getting [cached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51384973/jmeter-what-is-difference-between-use-or-vars-get-to-get-value-of-variable)

> ensure the script does not use any variable using ${varName} as caching would take only first value of ${varName}. Instead use : vars.get("varName")

Answer (score 0):

As per [JSR223 Sampler documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler):

> The JSR223 test elements have a feature (compilation) that can significantly increase performance. To benefit from this feature:
>
> - Use Script files instead of inlining them. This will make JMeter compile them if this feature is available on ScriptEngine and cache them.
> - Or Use Script Text and check Cache compiled script if available property.>
>
>   ```
>   When using this feature, ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code as caching would only cache first replacement. Instead use script parameters.
>   ```

So either put your `${__jm__myLoopControllerName__idx}` to "Parameters" section and refer it as "Parameters" in your script:

[image]

or use [`vars` shorthand for JMeterVariables class instance](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) like:

```
vars.get('__jm__myLoopControllerName__idx')
```

[image]